# How to ssh into cloud shell vm through putty and how to see a port on cloud-shell without webpreview

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was using cloud shell I can ssh into cloud shell  using

```
gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh
```

Now I wanted to connect to this vm using putty is there any way of doing it

I also wanted to do a web preview a port on cloud shell vm
Using curl how do I do it rather than viewing port from my browser

Comment: Have a read at the following and see if that answers your question:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

and

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced

Also ... if you have two questions, please create two separate questions rather than one question with two combined questions within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**cloud-shell is not a vm:** cloud shell is a docker container its not a vm
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/environment/view

**How do i connect to cloud-shell using putty:**

```
  gcloud alpha cloud-shell  --dry-run
```

you will get a clear picture of how you were able to ssh into your cloud shell container using gcloud sdk here you will be able to see the public ip of your cloud-shell container it runs 
it looks as follows.if you observe the output of your dry run command you can see the ephemeral public ip of your cloud shell container. so now you can use this ephemeral public ip to ssh into it  from port 6000 using the private key that is  ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine . However it being a ephemeral ip gets changed frequently and you have to update in your putty settings every time your public ip gets changed.

```
    /usr/bin/ssh -t -p 6000 -i /home/<user_home>/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@ephemeral-public-ip -- DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=<project_uid> bash -l
```

using the public ip generated in the above command and using the private key in .ssh folder of your home directory you can connect to cloud-shell vm using putty

**How do i see a port in cloud-shell using public ip:**

cloud-shell firewall rules prevent you from viewing a port with its public ip: even though  you  have got the public ip of your cloud-shell container   you can't access other ports of  it because the cloud-shell providers might be allowing only ssh and remaining other traffic will be blocked by the firewall  hence you cant access them using public ip.

**how do i do a webpreview from shell:**

you can use putty to connect to the cloud-shell and use the tunnel feature in putty where you can map a specific port of your remote vm to a port on your host where putty is running and you can access it using localhost:<port-mapped>

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty/

Comment: This works for me on MacOS: `CLOUDSHELL_IP=$(gcloud cloud-shell ssh --dry-run | sed -e :begin -e '$!N;s/\n/ /;tbegin' | sed -E 's/.+admin_@([^ ]+) .+/\1/')`